# How to check that field exists in every array item and is non-empty

Tags: json, spring-cloud-contract

Suppose I have a contract like this:

```
org.springframework.cloud.contract.spec.Contract.make {
request {
    method "GET"
    url "/api/profiles"
    headers {
        header('Accept': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8')
        header('Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8')
    }
}
response {
    status 200
    headers {
        header('Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8')
    }
    body(
            value(
                    stub(
                            '''\
                    [
                      {
                        "profile": "profile1",
                      },
                      {
                        "profile": "profile2",
                      }
                    ]   
                    '''
                    ),
                    test(
                            [
                                    [
                                            "profile" : regex(nonEmpty()),
                                    ]
                            ]
                    )
            )
    )
}
```

The test of `"profile" : regex(nonEmpty())` only checks that there is at least one array entry with a `profile` attribute that is non empty.

I would like to test that all entries have a non-empty `profile`.

I already tried this using test matchers:

```
jsonPath('$.[*].profile', byRegex(nonEmpty()))
```

While this checks every `profile` field to be non-empty, it doesn't check whether such a field actually exists.

How can I test that a `profile` field exists in every array entry and that each one is non-empty?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the easiest way will be to use `byCommand` in the `testMatchers` section and pass the list there. Then manually assert whatever you want programmatically.

Comment: Thanks. Just to clarify, the preexisting matchers are only meant to test single entries?

Comment: I think I describe it really thoroughly here (http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Edgware.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud.html#_dynamic_properties_in_the_matchers_sections). It will assert whatever you pass as a json path. List, single entry, map etc.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't find a clarification there. If anything, I am more confused now. It was my expectation that I could assert each object in an array. Your original answer indicates that this is only possible by asserting programmatically. Is that true?

Comment: If you can't write them via json path assertion then you have to do it programmatically